# read stream & direct stream into file in typescript

Tags: typescript, fs

I am using node with typescript.

I need to read large file as stream and direct write it into file using typescript with node js.

It is giving me error .

Error : The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Object

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { createReadStream, writeFile } from 'fs';
const { createServer,http } = require('http');
var parse = require('csv-parser');
var csv = require('fast-csv');
const options = { headers: true, quoteColumns: true };
const { writeToPath } = require('@fast-csv/format');
const { convertArrayToCSV } = require('convert-array-to-csv');

try {

   var csvData= [];
   const stream = createReadStream(__dirname+'/content/readsample1.csv', { 
                 highWaterMark: 9000, encoding: 'utf8'});
   stream.pipe(parse({}))
   .on('data', (csvrow: any)  => {
       console.log(csvrow)
       fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'/content/someDatas1.csv',csvrow, { flag: 'a' })
   })
   .on('error', () => {
      console.log(" in console error ")
   })
   .on('end', () => {
       console.log('done')
   }) 

  } catch (err) {

   console.error(err)
 }
```

Can anyone help me how to overcome from this ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's much later and the problem not an issue any more.

I think your mistake is in these lines:

```
   .on('data', (csvrow: any)  => {
       console.log(csvrow)
```

there you say `csvrow` is allowed to have any type but it may only be of type `string` or an instance of `Buffer`, `TypedArray`, or `DataView`.